# ADAPTAR TEXTO AL TAMAÑO EN UN IMAGESTRING() PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

//ASI COMO LO TENGO ME IMPRIME LA IMAGEN PERO SOLO SE MUESTRAN LAS PALABRAS INICIALES, YA QUE LO //MANEJA TODO MI TEXTO SOBRE UNA SOLA LINEA Y MUESTRA SOLO LAS PALABRAS QUE ALCANZAR A ENTRAR EN //LA IMAGEN

```
<?php
$img = imagecreate(500, 500);//TAMAÑO DE LA IMAGEN
$textbgcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);// COLOR DE FONDO
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);//COLOR DEL TEXTO


$txt = $fila['texto'];// TEXTO QUE ES TRAIDO DE MI BD 
imagestring($img, 5, 0, 0, $txt, $textcolor);//CREANDO EL RESULTADO

ob_start();
imagepng($img);
printf('<center><img src="data:image/png;base64,%s"/></center>',base64_encode(ob_get_clean()));
?>
```

Comment: No redactes en mayúsculas por favor pues equivale a gritar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hice un ejemplo que te podría ayudar para que lo pruebes, en el código comenté cada parte y lo explico.

```
<?php

$img = imagecreate(500, 500);//TAMAÑO DE LA IMAGEN

$textbgcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 2, 255);// COLOR DE FONDO
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0); //COLOR DEL TEXTO

$textoEjemplo = "/ASI COMO LO TENGO ME IMPRIME LA IMAGEN PERO \n SOLO SE MUESTRAN LAS PALABRAS INICIALES, YA QUE LO //MANEJA TODO MI TEXTO SOBRE UNA SOLA LINEA Y MUESTRA SOLO LAS PALABRAS QUE ALCANZAR A ENTRAR EN //LA IMAGEN";

$txt = $textoEjemplo;

$txt = wordwrap($txt, (500/10)); 
/** 
 * Añade saltos de linea \n al texto, 
 * cada x n de caracteres, en este caso 
 * el ancho de la imagen dividido entre 10, 
 * resultado: salto de linea cada 50 caracteres
*/

$lines = explode("\n", $txt); // Separa el texto por los saltos de linea \n y lo convierte en un array

$lineHeight = 15; // Altura entre parrafos
$padding = 20; // Relleno para que no esté pegado al borde de la imagen
$nextLinePosition = $padding; // Posición en la que estará la linea de texto

// Recorremos el array de texto y vamos añadiendo el texto a la imagen
foreach($lines as $line){
    imagestring($img, 5, $padding, $nextLinePosition, trim($line), $textcolor);
    $nextLinePosition += $lineHeight;
}

ob_start();
imagepng($img);
printf('<center><img src="data:image/png;base64,%s"/></center>',base64_encode(ob_get_clean()));

?>
```